# Feature Request: Gazebo Version Number in Help -> About

Tags: gazebo

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

The pop-up About dialog window should have the version number included there, to make debugging and usage easier. This is standard in most all applications.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/817/feature-request:-gazebo-version-number-in-help--%3E-about/) by [davetcoleman](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/134/davetcoleman/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 369 on 2013-01-14

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Jose Luis Rivero](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/152/jose-luis-rivero/) on 2013-03-13**:
Fixed. Would you mind mark it as answered?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Here is a pull-request to fix this issue:
https://bitbucket.org/osrf/gazebo/pull-request/231/updated-the-about-dialog-box-under-the/diff

---

Originally posted by [nkoenig](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/5/nkoenig/) with karma: 7676 on 2013-01-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [davetcoleman](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/134/davetcoleman/) on 2013-01-15**:
That should make verifying I'm using the right Gazebo easier, thanks!